# Recommended E-Commerce Platform for Power Users (Highly Customizable)?

Tags: hosting, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm the primary tech guy for an e-commerce site that gets 700k pageviews/mo. and does over $1M/yr. in online revenue.  We've long outgrown our in-house LAMP e-commerce application and I'm searching for alternatives.

I've looked at almost every OSS shopping cart I could get my hands on, but none of them have met our needs.  I've pretty much come to the conclusion that we're going to have to go with a hosted solution (which isn't all bad, since it offloads a lot of work from me.)  However, most of the hosted solutions I'm seeing are designed for the typical small business owner who simply wants to sell widgets from his garage.  I need something that is more aimed at a customer who already has qualified technical staff to implement the solution.  Our needs include:

- Integration with Google Checkout.  Our company president formerly worked on the project while at Google.  It's a no-go if we suggest something else.  He's also a Google Analytics addict therefore that is a requirement as well.
- Powerful API to get data both in and out of the e-commerce platform.  This will need to integrate with our CRM application and accounting systems.
- Interface has to be fully customizable.  This would primarily be done with CSS, but CMS-liked editing feature for non-technical staff would be a huge bonus.  This is what has kept us on our home-grown system for so long.
- If the solution is installed rather than hosted, it will have to run on Linux.  We don't use Windows on the backend and are not likely to consider doing so anytime soon.

What I've looked at so far:

- Yahoo Shopping (Sales rep I talked to was iffy about Google Checkout support.  Deal breaker)
- Prostores (I've learned the hard way not to tie a business to any company associated with Ebay)
- Nexternal (Sample store unimpressive and unacceptably slow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with BigCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com) would be my best suggestion but you could look at [PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com).

Comment: Magento is not a viable solution.  It's (deliberately) difficult to customize, and dog slow/inflexible due to the stupid EAV architecture.  However, I will look at PrestaShop.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I just remembered about Cubecart at http://www.cubecart.com/. Take a look as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about [OsCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com)? It's very customizable and there are tons of additional checkout options and free extensions available for it.

Comment: OsCommerce verges on abandonware and lacks a lot of the newer features of e-commerce platforms.  It's internal architecture is also a mess, making it difficult to customize. (I mean customize at a functional level, not customize via included settings).  The platform was never designed for a site like ours and it would be non-trivial to shoehorn it into our system.  The same holds true of its derivative, ZenCart.

Answer (score 0):

The host that I use http://www.Station5.net has auto installs for osCommerce, Zen Cart, and nopCommerce. I used osCommerce and it was very simple to install. It is very customizable from the front end, but if you need to you can always open up the code and add any new functionality you need as long as you know PHP. Another option for you could be to use the Joomla CMS and add the shopping cart features that you need to that. There are a lot of shopping cart plugins for Joomla so you can customize it with the features you need. You can find them in the extension directory on the Joomla site.